# Nokia Asha LWUIT UIID and source code

Tags: lwuit, nokia

I have to develop an application for Nokia Asha 501. I am using Nokia SDK 1.1 and the library S40-asha2013 from the ${SDK_HOME}/plugins/lwuit/lib.

I am trying to figure it out the UIID stuff from all the examples I am studying, but I couldn't find a source that would list all the UIID values for the components. For example I could change the background color of a normal TextField only if I set the UIID to "Label"

Ex:

```
textField.setUIID("Label");
```

Or to make for example a green button you have to set the UIID like this:

```
saveBtn.setUIID("ButtonGreen");
```

Which let's be honest do not makes any sense. So my question is does anyway know where I can find some documentation or listing related to this "mysterious" UIID. Or at least does anyone know where or if I can find the sources to Nokia Asha Lwuit because I only found this https://java.net/projects/lwuit/sources/svn/show but doesn't seem to be the same library (the version for my lwuit is 1.1.2).

With source code available I could look myself in the code and check for all UIID's.

Edit:

As a piece of advice if you want to really ease your life and understand how style and look is handled in LWUIT the resource editor tool is very valuable. Only after I opened the Nokia Asha default resource in Resource Editor I actually understood what happens there and what is the thing with UIID's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had also the experience that some styles seem to be "hardcoded", like the background of a text field. I had a suprising effect with an alert. When I set styles in resource editor they get ignored.
I also did not found the latest Nokia sources.

You get a list of all used UUIDs when you open the lwuit-jar file with a zip program, for example 7.zip, andd extract the file asha2013_themes. You can then open this file with the resource editor.

You can try to ask in the Nokia developer forum:
http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Discussion/forumdisplay.php/324-Mobile-Java-UI-and-User-Experience